# how to add puzzle part shadow on move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I do a game like jigsaw puzzle, i face issue when i move or scroll my puzzle parts then parts shadow came with it, like below image.
[image: puzzle part shadow image]
i tried `canvas.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width,this.canvas.height);` but it couldn't help me.

my js code [here](http://104.128.228.134/game2/js/jigsaw.js) and i want like [this](http://www.jigsawplanet.com/?rc=play&pid=3c8a95bf0dac&pieces=24) on mouse move or drag time.

Answer (score 2):

**How to reuse a shadow for efficiency**

Adding a shadow is one of the most expensive tasks that canvas does. So you might not want to recalculate the shadow with every mousemove. Instead, you might create a single shadow for each piece-shape at the start of your app. Then reuse the shadow during mousemove by first drawing the shadow and then drawing the piece image on top of the shadow.

Assume you have a jigsaw puzzle and many (but not all) of the pieces have this `slot-tab-slot-tab` shape:

[image] ... and ... [image]

Then you can create one single shadow image that will fit under any of the `slot-tab-slot-tab` shapes to give that shape a shadow:

[image]

So if you first draw the shadow and then draw any `slot-tab-slot-tab` piece on top of that shadow you have **one shadow serving any piece with that shape**:

[image] ... and ... [image]

**Here's annotated code and a Demo:**

```js
// canvas vars
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
    var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    offsetX=BB.left;
    offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

// jigsaw vars
var pieces=[];
var shadows=[];
var blurSize=10;
// jigsaw piece#1
var piece1=new Image();
piece1.onload=start;
piece1.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/Piece1.png";
// jigsaw piece#2
var piece2=new Image();
piece2.onload=start;
piece2.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/Piece2.png";
var imgcount=2;
// start() after all images are fully loaded
function start(){
    if(--imgcount>0){return;}

    // create piece definitions
    pieces.push({img:piece1,x:25,y:75,w:piece1.width,h:piece1.height,shadowIndex:0,showShadow:false});
    pieces.push({img:piece2,x:300,y:75,w:piece2.width,h:piece2.height,shadowIndex:0,showShadow:false});
    
    // make one shadow that fits all pieces with this outline
    shadows.push(makeShadowUnderlay(piece1,blurSize));
    
    // draw the pieces
    drawAllPieces();
    
    // listen for mouse events
    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUpOut(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseUpOut(e);});
}

function drawAllPieces(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    for(var i=0;i<pieces.length;i++){
        drawPiece(i);
    }
}

function drawPiece(pieceIndex){
    // cache the piece
    var piece=pieces[pieceIndex];
    // draw the shadow, if desired
    if(piece.showShadow){
        var shadow=shadows[piece.shadowIndex]
        ctx.drawImage(shadow,piece.x-blurSize,piece.y-blurSize);
    }
    // draw the piece
    ctx.drawImage(piece.img,piece.x,piece.y);
}


function makeShadowUnderlay(img,blurSize){
    // create a new canvas containing the shadowed
    // outline of the img
    var c=document.createElement('canvas');
    var cctx=c.getContext('2d');
    c.width=img.width+blurSize*2;
    c.height=img.height+blurSize*2;
    cctx.shadowColor='black';
    cctx.shadowBlur=blurSize;
    cctx.shadowOffsetX=500;
    cctx.drawImage(img,blurSize-500,blurSize);
    return(c);
}

function handleMouseDown(e){
    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // get mouse postion
    var mx=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
    var my=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
    // set showShadow flag for any piece(s) under mouse
    for(var i=0;i<pieces.length;i++){
        var p=pieces[i];
        p.showShadow=false;
        if(mx>p.x && mx<p.x+p.w && my>p.y && my<p.y+p.h){
            p.showShadow=true;
        }
    }
    // redraw all pieces
    drawAllPieces();
}
//
function handleMouseUpOut(e){
    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // clear all shadow flags
    for(var i=0;i<pieces.length;i++){ pieces[i].showShadow=false; }
    // redraw all pieces
    drawAllPieces();    
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Mousedown on piece to shadow it using a reusable(!) shadow image</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=600 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: this code is perfect but when i used this code  then problem occurs related to  blur parts at move time like above images.

Comment: @foram Pardon, but I didn't understand your comment. :-//

Comment: in my JavaScript code mouse down event occurs at a time call draw function but not draw single parts it draw all parts again so that shadow display in all parts and one more thing at a time of drag one parts blur shadow display same as above image in question.

Comment: please check http://104.128.228.134/game2  this URL you can understand which problem i am facing right now.

Comment: I've edited the example to show how to optionally draw a shadow around one piece, while not shadowing a different piece. Importantly, the shadow is stopped with `context.shadowColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'`. Cheers!

Comment: @markE .. i want like that in your answer example. but on drag time put shadow on mycanvas. and when i focus out that canvas then it remove it shadow.. can you help me out for that thing! :)

Comment: @markE , okay i got solution from [here](http://html5.litten.com/how-to-drag-and-drop-on-an-html5-canvas/). my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/35fon4oq/)

Comment: @Himanshu. Your fiddle works, but keep in mind that adding a shadow is one of the most expensive tasks that canvas does. So you might not want to recalculate the shadow with every mousemove. Instead, you might create a separate in-memory canvas for each piece+shadow. Then reuse the in-memory piece+shadow during mousemove. ;-)

Comment: @markE can you create some line of code i don't understood very well how to do it.. in that way.

Comment: @Himanshu. An outline: (1) Create an in-memory canvas with `var piece1=document.createElement`, (2) Resize the canvas to the size of a puzzle piece, (3) Draw your puzzle piece with shadow onto the canvas, (4) When mousemove-ing use `drawImage(piece1,x,y)` to reuse the already created & shadowed piece1. Repeat #1-4 for all pieces. Cheers!

Comment: @markE Thank you for your quick reply, let me try this one!!. ;-).

Comment: @markE please check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/35fon4oq/4/). i just got confused there.

Comment: @Himanshu. I've added to my answer showing how to create and reuse a shadow (image) to avoid the expensive shadow calculations. Good luck with your project!